# List custom resources from caching client with custom fieldSelector

Tags: go, kubernetes, operator-sdk

I'm using the [Operator SDK](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk) to build a custom Kubernetes operator. I have created a custom resource definition and a controller using the respective Operator SDK commands:

```
operator-sdk add api --api-version example.com/v1alpha1 --kind=Example
operator-sdk add controller --api-version example.com/v1alpha1 --kind=Example
```

Within the main reconciliation loop (for the example above, the auto-generated `ReconcileExample.Reconcile` method) I have some custom business logic that requires me to query the Kubernetes API for other objects of the same kind that have a certain field value. It's occurred to me that I might be able to use the default API client (that is provided by the controller) with a custom field selector:

```
func (r *ReconcileExample) Reconcile(request reconcile.Request) (reconcile.Result, error) {
    ctx := context.TODO()
    listOptions := client.ListOptions{
        FieldSelector: fields.SelectorFromSet(fields.Set{"spec.someField": "someValue"}),
        Namespace:     request.Namespace,
    }
    otherExamples := v1alpha1.ExampleList{}

    if err := r.client.List(ctx, &listOptions, &otherExamples); err != nil {
        return reconcile.Result{}, err
    }

    // do stuff...

    return reconcile.Result{}, nil
}
```

When I run the operator and create a new `Example` resource, the operator fails with the following error message:

```
{"level":"info","ts":1563388786.825384,"logger":"controller_example","msg":"Reconciling Example","Request.Namespace":"default","Request.Name":"example-test"}
{"level":"error","ts":1563388786.8255732,"logger":"kubebuilder.controller","msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"example-controller","request":"default/example-test","error":"Index with name field:spec.someField does not exist","stacktrace":"..."}
```

The most important part being

> Index with name field:spec.someField does not exist

I've already searched [the Operator SDK's documentation](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/blob/master/doc/user/client.md) on the default API client and learned a bit about the inner workings of the client, but no detailed explanation on this error or how to fix it.

**What does this error message mean, and how can I create this missing index to efficiently list objects by this field value?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default API client that is provided by the controller is a *split client* -- it serves `Get` and `List` requests from a locally-held cache and forwards other methods like `Create` and `Update` directly to the Kubernetes API server. This is also explained in [the respective documentation](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/blob/master/doc/user/client.md#default-client):

> The SDK will generate code to create a Manager, which holds a Cache and a Client to be used in CRUD operations and communicate with the API server. By default a Controller's Reconciler will be populated with the Manager's Client which is a split-client. [...] A split client reads (Get and List) from the Cache and writes (Create, Update, Delete) to the API server. Reading from the Cache significantly reduces request load on the API server; as long as the Cache is updated by the API server, read operations are eventually consistent.

To query values from the cache using a custom field selector, the cache needs to have a *search index* for this field. This indexer can be defined right after the cache has been set up.

To register a custom indexer, add the following code into the bootstrapping logic of the operator (in the auto-generated code, this is done directly in `main`). This needs to be done **after** the controller manager has been instantiated (`manager.New`) and **also after** the custom API types have been added to the `runtime.Scheme`:

```
package main

import (
    k8sruntime "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime"
    "example.com/example-operator/pkg/apis/example/v1alpha1"
    // ...
)

function main() {
    // ...

    cache := mgr.GetCache()

    indexFunc := func(obj k8sruntime.Object) []string {
        return []string{obj.(*v1alpha1.Example).Spec.SomeField}
    }

    if err := cache.IndexField(&v1alpha1.Example{}, "spec.someField", indexFunc); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // ...
}
```

When a respective indexer function is defined, field selectors on `spec.someField` will work from the local cache as expected.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, @helmbert. The updated link for Default Client is https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/references/client/#default-client